# What is the male form of fashionista?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I run a fashion website and am a guy. I'm not a fashionista, but something else, right? What would I be?

Comment: What research have you done to suggest you are not a fashionista? Questions are generally expected to show some evidence of prior research. There is plenty of general information available on this word that you should incorporate into your question, should you still have one after looking it over.

Comment: Why would you think all *-ista* words would necessarily be restricted to non-guys?

Answer (score 3):

The word looks like it's based on Italian, which has in turn borrowed the term, to the Italian word is now also "fashionista"!

The "-ista" ending, eg "chitarrista" (guitarist), "pianista" "acquarellista" (watercolour painter), etc, doesn't change regardless of whether the person it describes is male or female. So. while in Italian a male teacher is a "professore" and female is a "professoressa", a male fashionista is still a fashionista, just as Elton John is a "pianista" or Miles Davis a "jazzista". So, in short, you are a "fashionista".

Best of luck for your website!

Comment: Good luck with explaining this to someone who looks at you funny for referring to yourself as a "fashionista"

Comment: It's almost certainly from [Spanish](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137550/what-english-words-employ-the-spanish-suffix-ista), not Italian.

Comment: A man or woman who makes overpriced coffee is a "barista" (even though the term originally just means someone who works behind a counter, as far as I know.  Very off-topic though. Oops!).

Comment: @PhilMJones It turns out that *barista* is not an RAE-accepted Spanish word. *Barrista* exists, but refers to a gymnast (well, or circus performer) who specializes in the parallel bars. Even though Spanish has borrowed the English word *bar* for the same thing as we use it for — a drinking establishment with an actual bar (*una barra*) in it — my hackles raise up looking for another *r* in the English *barista*.  It doesn’t even sound right pronounced in Spanish without the second *r*.